# How retrieve date and time from database according to login user using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve date and time according to login user in my ASP.NET web application using C#. The code I'm using is just returning the 1st row details.

I want date and time of current login user and bind it to with a label.

I have a table called `Userdatatext` with 3 columns:

```
UserName, UserText, LastEditTime
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks in advance :)

My C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["userName"] != null && Session["userName"] != "")
    {
        LblUser.Text = "Welcome " + Session["userName"].ToString() + "";
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }

    try
    {
        string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbLogns"].ToString();

        SqlConnection objConection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
        objConection.Open();

        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("select LastEditTime from Userdatatext where UserName='" + Session["userName"] + "'", objConection);

        DataSet objDataset = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
        objAdapter.Fill(objDataset);

        string lastdatetime = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        Lbllastedit.Text = "Last edit on :-" + lastdatetime;
        Lbllastedit.Font.Size = 15;

        objConection.Close();
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfRangeException n)
    {
        Lbllastedit.Text = "Last edit :- no data found !";
        Lbllastedit.Font.Size = 13;
    }
}
```

Comment: You still need to do lots of work, save all the entries in UTC format, save the user's preferred time zone/current time zone of user. Save it into database. when you retrieve convert the utc entry to the user's timezone.

Comment: I don't know your database, but it seems like there would only be one row per user. Can you try to explain the problem again? What do you expect to get and what are you actually getting?

Comment: My database is mysql server.when a user login i want that user's last edit date and time from data base and bind it with leble.inserting time and all i have done it but how to do this? as per above code i only get 1st customer date and time.@Crowcoder

Comment: No offense, but your code would fail a review in many ways, but if we are going to start with one problem it is how you get the connection string. You don't want `ToString()`, you want: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbLogns"].ConnectionString`

Comment: Ok @Crowcoder , but do you have any solutions.leave the connection string.

Comment: I can't answer because you haven't explained the problem well. You mention "first row details" but you also imply you cannot set the Label text. What **exactly** is happening? Do you get an exception? And if so what are the complete details?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: ok i have a table "Usetestdata" and it has 3 column - username,usertext and lastedittime.when a user login and edit his text it goes to the database with current time.When that user log in again i want his last edited time.as per my code i only get always 1st user date and time.hope you understand @Crowcoder

Comment: Thanks man @marc_s i will go through it.

Comment: If there are multiple rows per user you need to use `SELECT MAX(LastEditTime)...` to get the latest one or you can `ORDER BY LastEditTime DESC` and grab the first row as you are doing.

Comment: i found my solution, thanks @Crowcoder

Comment: thanks for help @justcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code with a `SqlDataReader`:

```
try
{
    string lastdatetime = null;

    string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbLogns"].ToString();

    SqlConnection objConection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
    objConection.Open();

    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("select LastEditTime from Userdatatext where UserName='" + Session["userName"] + "'", objConection);

    SqlDataReader dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        lastdatetime = dr["LastEditTime"].ToString();
    }

    dr.Close();          

    Lbllastedit.Text = "Last edit on :-" + lastdatetime;
    Lbllastedit.Font.Size = 15;

    objConection.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is **STILL** highly vulnerable to **SQL injection** - you should really **NOT** recommend such a bad solution - **USE PARAMETERS!** Always ...

Comment: I understand this answer is using the ops original code, however it should really follow best practices to avoid misleading future users: using statements, parameters, connection string